Display DWG file on a web page and plot the points on the dwg using the coordinates of the dwg
Is there possible way in which i can display a DWG , a CAD design of floor and plot points on the CAD using the coordinates with respect to the CAD?
A possible approach to present this problem.
Should not use any 3rd party application

"Should not use any 3rd party application" => you've to write the app yourself, DWG files can't natively be shown or edited on a browser.
